# How to find why NSMutableData is invalid

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest, nsmutabledata

I access a RESTFUL url and get back results.  The results are in JSON.  I turn the response into a string via:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection   *)connection {
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[self.receivedData mutableBytes] length:[self.receivedData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The json variable has a value of 0x0.  When I mouse over it, I see `<Invalid CFStringRef`>.  How can I debug this to tell why it is invalid?  I render the JSON given back through the browser in A JSON parser.  That checks out fine.

Results are given back by entering an ID in the URL.  Other IDs return results without issue.  The result set is fairly large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would use `initWithData:encoding:` to setup the NSString. Small difference, but that method is there for a reason.

Then, I would do a hexdump of `self.receivedData` to see what is actually in there. If that data is not properly UTF8 encoded then the `initWithData:encoding:` will fail.

(Google for NSData hex dump to find other people's utility functions to do this)

I have found that sometimes web services are sloppy with their encoding. So I usually implement a fallback like this:

```
NSString* html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (html == nil) {
    html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    if (html == nil) {
        html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
    }
}
```

It is kind of sad that this is required but many web services are not written or configured properly.

Comment: Thanks.  Your technique is definitely giving back some better info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSLog` to look at the bytes.

Comment: And if the bytes represent data as a string, you can cut and paste them into 0xED to make viewing super easy: http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/0xed.html